# How to work with variables dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to work with variables dynamically, and get them dynamically too. The first thing I need to know is:

How to save a variable reference(NOT its value) in a collection?

Example:

```
var divA = "<div>my div A</div>";
var divB = "<div>my div B</div>";
var divC = "<div>my div C</div>";
```

Then, save in a collection:

```
var mySet = new Set();

function returnDivA(){
 return divA; 
}

function returnDivB(){
 return divB; 
}

function returnDivC(){
 return divC; 
}

mySet.add(returnDivA());//I would like save the varible ref in a collection.
mySet.add(returnDivB());
mySet.add(returnDivC());
```

I want the Set collection to save the variables(NOT its values), it means:

```
var mySet = new Set(divA, divB, divC);
```

Then, with that, my intent is to do something like that:

```
var totalOfDivs;
for(var i = 0; i < mySet.size; i++){
  totalOfDivs += mySet[i];
}

$("#anotherDIV_to_show_all_divs").html(totalOfDivs);//Then, here, I want to show all divs in the screen.
```

I would like suggestions, please!

Comment: There is no "reference", all variables are pass-by-value in javascript, and when it comes to strings, they are immutable and can't be changed anyway?

Comment: It really looks like you should be using more jQuery, and an array, that way you could do just `.html(arr.join(''))`, and of course, if you use jQuery to create the elements, you'd have objects, and could at least pass them as a value of a reference.

Comment: Try `$("#anotherDIV_to_show_all_divs").append(mySet[i]);` in for loop. You won't have reference to element, but it will do what you want to.

Comment: adeneo, can you explained more detailed, please? arr.join will take all the variables and join then?

Answer (score 0):

It solved my problem to put variable dynamically in html using this in a **for loop**:

```
$("#anotherDIV_to_show_all_divs").append(mySet[i]);
```

About saving javascript variable reference in a Collection, I understand that I can't do that, because of the answer of the adeneo in comment:

"There is no "reference", all variables are pass-by-value in javascript..."

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation about set.

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

I guess you have to loop your set like this.

```
var totalOfDivs= "";

    for (let item of mySet.values()) {
        totalOfDivs+= item;
        //console.log(item); 
    }

$("#anotherDIV_to_show_all_divs").html(totalOfDivs);
```

Comment: You're right about it. After I have used Set I did it(in my real code) : Array.from(mySetVariableHere) and then I have used the for loop.